# Index of the newly inserted row in JQUERY Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm tying to insert new row to JQUERY datatable using row.add method

```
var oTable = $('#table_question').DataTable();
//var row = oTable.row($(star).parents('tr:first')).data()
oTable.row.add(['', '', '']);
```

But how could we get the index or data of the newly inserted row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()

```
row.add()
```

This has a return value of

> DataTables API instance with the newly added row in its result set.

So you need to store the row instance to another variable, and call `row(),data()`. In your case the easiest would be,

```
var new_row = oTable.row.add(['', '', '']).data();
console.log(row(new_row).data());
```

You can refer the

```
row().data()
```

API here, https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()